# When 2 users are logged in simultaneously in Windows 10, is it possible for the audio from both to play, like in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-10, audio, user-accounts, fast-user-switching

I keep my personal Windows account and apps separate from my work account. I'm usually logged into both at once, and just switch with Win+L.

I'd like to get the "message received" audio notifications from my work email client, chat apps, etc, while using my personal account, so I don't miss anything when I'm on my personal account.

Back in the Windows 7 days, this was possible, since switching users wouldn't mute the other user. This seems to have stopped working in Windows 10 (or perhaps 8).

I'm ready to disable any privacy protection (from other local users, not Microsoft) to get this working.

What I don't want:

a) to log in to the work apps on my personal account. I use 2 accounts for a reason.

b) install work apps on my personal phone and get notifications there